# Only a single type was generated by @genType

Tags: typescript, reason, bucklescript

After adding ReasonML to a React-Native typeScript codebase, I found that only a single type was generated by @genType, even though these two functions were transpiled by BuckleScript successfully. How to fix this problem?

**reasonSum.re**

```
[@genType]
let reasonSum = (a, b) => a + b;
let reasonSum2 = (a, b) => a + b;
```

**reasonSum.gen.tsx**

```
/* TypeScript file generated from reasonSum.re by genType. */
/* eslint-disable import/first */

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-var-requires
const Curry = require('bs-platform/lib/es6/curry.js');

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-var-requires
const reasonSumBS = require('./reasonSum.bs');

export const reasonSum: (a:number, b:number) => number = function (Arg1: any, Arg2: any) {
  const result = Curry._2(reasonSumBS.reasonSum, Arg1, Arg2);
  return result
};
```

**bsconfig.json**

```
{
  "name": "reason-in-react-typescript",
  "sources": [
    {
      "dir": "./reason",
      "subdirs": true
    }
  ],
  "package-specs": [
    {
      "module": "es6-global",
      "in-source": true
    }
  ],
  "bs-dependencies": [
    "@glennsl/bs-json",
    "bs-fetch"
  ],
  "suffix": ".bs.js",
  "namespace": true,
  "refmt": 3,
  "gentypeconfig": {
    "language": "typescript",
    "module": "es6",
    "importPath": "relative",
    "shims": {
      "Js": "Js",
      "React": "ReactShim",
      "ReactEvent": "ReactEvent",
      "ReasonPervasives": "ReasonPervasives",
      "ReasonReact": "ReactShim"
    },
    "debug": {
      "all": false
    },
    "exportInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an attribute attached to a single item all only apply to that item. It's possible to make the attribute stand-alone by not associating it with a specific item, which might be interpreted as being associated with the module it's contained in, but I don't think `genType` supports that. Instead it seems you'll have to add an attribute to each item you want to export:

```
[@genType]
let reasonSum = (a, b) => a + b;
[@genType]
let reasonSum2 = (a, b) => a + b;
```